# My pre-loader is not working as expected, Animation not work

Tags: javascript, html, loader, preloader

Want to create the pre-loader page, and have reference URL "https://www.priyaty.com/".
But somehow I'm not able to create the same loader as the above link.

I'm facing an issue when I applied the few CSS but, somehow I'm not matched with the above link loader.

can anyone help me out to build the same loader?
I'm using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript

```js
function counter() {
  var count = setInterval(function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("counter")
    int = parseInt(c.textContent);
    c.textContent = (++int).toString();
    if (int == 100) {
      clearInterval(count);
      c.classList.add("hide");
      document.getElementById("preloader").classList.add("slide-up")
    }
  }, 40)
}
counter();
```

```css
.preloader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.preloader .preloaderp {
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .05);
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.preloader.slide-up {
  height: 0px;
  transition: .5s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  font-size: 0px;
}

.counter {
  font-size: 5em;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.counter.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s;
}

.counter::after {
  content: "%";
  font-size: .5em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 575px) {
  .preloaderp {
    font-size: 2em;
  }

  .counter {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="preloader" id="preloader">
    <p class="preloaderp">Loading</p>
    <div class="counter" id="counter">
        0
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were you looking for this?

```js
var counting = setInterval(function() {
  var loader = document.getElementById("loader");
  var currval = parseInt(loader.innerHTML);
  var Width = 100 - currval;
  var loadscreen = document.getElementById("loadscreen");
  loader.innerHTML = ++currval;
  if (currval === 100) {
    clearInterval(counting);
    loadscreen.style.display = "none";
  }
  loadscreen.style.transition = "0.1s";
  loadscreen.style.width = Width + "%";
}, 10);
```

```css
.loading-screen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.loader {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: Arial;
  position: fixed;
  left: 45%;
  z-index: 1000;
  color: red;
}

.loader:after {
  content: " %";
  font-size: 100%;
}

.after-load {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="loading-screen"></div>
<div class="after-load" id="loadscreen">
  <div class="loader" style="top: 50%;" id="loader">0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is quite the same but I want the same like https://www.priyaty.com/

Comment: I think that this fiddle should work: [https://jsfiddle.net/oxyg7s1h/](https://jsfiddle.net/oxyg7s1h/)

Comment: thanks! That what I want.. but now only text in and out (100% and Welcome) animation is missing, I'm looking into it but if you can help me out then it will batter for me.. but thanks buddy will appriciate your efforts.

Comment: I did try but, bad luck not able to apply animation.

Comment: Can you please help me with animated text @Happy_Coder, I did try but not getting succeeded.

Comment: @user14697373 can you please help?